# Breaking down long sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

I’m having trouble breaking down sentences in Japanese. A lot of the sentences in my book (Tobira) are so long and complicated for me!

Could someone please break down this sentence for me?

> 今会社で大きい問題になっているco2の削減に効果があるハイブリッド車の技術や、自動車のリイサイクルシステムについてもっと勉強したいと思っている。

I think I would like to study more about the big issues at my company such as (like), the technology of the hybrid car that has an effect on cutting co2 and Auto mobiles recycling systems.

This one is what I’ve translated it into but in order for it to take this shape, doesn’t など need to be in there? Or is it implied by the usage of や?

If the translation is wrong or needs changes please let me know and fee

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your problem, but doesn't について fulfill the role you think など should have?

Comment: Is it truly 会社, not 社会? I'm also worried about リイサイクルシステム, which might be the typo of リサイクルシステム (though I don't have the privilege for editing a question.)

Comment: Thank you this was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

今会社で = Yeah, I think this is 社会

大きい問題になっているCO2 = "CO2 which has become a big problem"

CO2の削減に効果があるハイブリッド車 = "Hybrid car which is effective in reducing CO2"

車の技術や、 = "car technology"

自動車のリイサイクルシステム = "automobile recycling system"

についてもっと勉強したいと思っている。 = "I would like to study more about..."

Stringing these together, you can translate this to "I would like to study more about hybrid cars which are effective in reducing CO2--which has become a problem in our present society--and automobile recycling systems (among other things)."

It does still look awkward, so feel free to revise it. I'd do it like this:
"I'd like to study more about automobile recycling systems and hybrid cars which are effective in reducing the big problem that is CO2 in our present society."

Comment: Probably the CO2の削減 is the "big problem". The final translation you've offered seems to miss out that "become a big problem" part of the original.

Comment: Thanks @Ben for that! I am tempted to translate it to "growing problem" but that would be "なっていく" and not "なっている” in Japanese, right? I've edited my answer to include your suggestion. I know I should have said "become a big problem" instead of "is a problem" but I think it's close enough, considering that ている focuses on the effect of a prior action on the present rather than on the action itself. Or am I wrong?